# How can keep these values in my list, they only execute when they're listed as strings, but then they have no value?

Tags: string, python-2.7, integer, blackjack

Cant return my "suits" list in the random unless it is strings but i want to keep the values! Anything missing or any way I can force them later in my black jack game?

```
    import random
    import itertools
    Ace = 11 
    Jack = 10
    Queen = 10  #trying to create an acurate point system held in these 
                 #variables ?
    King = 10
    suits = [' of Hearts', ' of Diamonds', ' of Spades', ' of Clubs']
    values = [Ace,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,Jack,Queen,King] #listed as
                                                 #variables and 
                                                       #integers?
    deck = tuple (''.join(card) for card in itertools.product
    (values,  suits)) #whats missing from this comprehension?
    hand = random.sample (deck, 2)


     TypeError                Traceback (most recentcall last)
     <ipython-input-102-7a66aeb023c0> in <module>()
     7 suits = [' of Hearts', ' of Diamonds', ' of Spades', ' of 
     Clubs']
     8 values = [Ace,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,Jack,Queen,King]
      ----> 9 deck = tuple (''.join(card) for card in itertools.product     
     (values, suits))
     10 hand = random.sample (deck, 2)

   <ipython-input-102-7a66aeb023c0> in <genexpr>((card,))
   7 suits = [' of Hearts', ' of Diamonds', ' of Spades', ' of Clubs']
   8 values = [Ace,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,Jack,Queen,King]
   ----> 9 deck = tuple (''.join(card) for card in itertools.product 
   (values, suits))
  10 hand = random.sample (deck, 2)

   TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

Comment: `join` only works on strings - maybe try `''.join(str(card))`

Comment: Why bother with strings at all except for output? Just use numbers for ranks, numbers for suits, and look up the strings only when needed.